# How often does processor cache flush?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Say I have a casual single-byte variable. I think on pretty much all systems single-byte operations are atomic, but if not please let me know. Now, say one thread updates this variable. How long should I expect/prepare for this update to appear in the other threads? I know I can put the update around mutexes/locks/barriers to make sure it's synchronized everywhere, but I'm curious about this. The wait time probably varies depending on whether the other threads are on separate processors/cores, and maybe depending on processor type.

Am I being logical for wondering this or have I greatly misunderstood something?

Comment: If you're writing any code that will rely on this kind of behavior, you might want to consider a different approach. Today's relaxed memory models can be very scary.

Comment: Short answer: between immediately and never. It depends on cpu architecture, what your other cpus are doing and the phase of the moon. There are cpu architectures out there where you will not see it unless you explicitly flush it. Also, be careful about considering writes to single bytes as "atomic" since they are more likely to happen in units of words rather then bytes and you might not get what you expect depending on cpu architecture.

Comment: For most architectures the cache does not have to flush for the changes to be visible, as CPUs can snoop into each other cache (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence). You should be more concerned about memory operation reordering.

Comment: @Suma, what do you mean by memory operation reordering and why is it likely to happen here ?

Answer (score 8):

Memory is synchronized as soon as you call a synchronization primitive/memory barrier such as `pthread_mutex_lock`. Aside from that, you should not assume any synchronization unless you're using C11 atomic types.

Answer (score 3):

In many architectures, the processor won't flush the cache until it *has to* - to make way for some more-needed data.

However, if the threads are sharing memory space, *and* you only have a single core, they will be able to see the update "immediately" from the cache. If it's actually been written from the CPU to memory.  Which it  may not be if the compiler's decided to keep it in a register, in which case your threads will all have their own "local" and incorrect copy.

As others have said, it's an interesting question - but the right answer for synchronising is to use proper synchronisation primitives!

Answer (score 0):

On MIPS architecture there is a sync instruction which serves as a load store barrier across cores i.e all loads and stores before issuing sync will happen before any load and stores after sync.Not sure about if there is an equivalent instruction in x86(assuming that is the architecture you are using).